# Divs not opening after load Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a comment/reply system.All divs are closed.User clicks on the comment they want to reply to.Div opens when clicked.User replies to a comment.The reply gets sent to database.Jquery/Ajax fetches the the reply message and loads but closes the divs where the user replied to the comment.

Jquery not showing my selected divs (after page load)???

comment/reply Code:

```
<div class='box'>
---- Comments from database code ----
</div>
<div class='feedback'>
----- Feedback from database code ---
</div>
<div class='replymsg'>
  <form class=".replyform">   
    <textarea class="replytext" ></textarea>
    <button class="replybutton" data-value="<?php echo $commentid; ?>">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="s"></div>
```

jQuery (open this box ie. divs not working):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".replybutton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("value"); // The id is the comment id so we can reply to this comment
    var replytext = $(this).prev().val();
    var foo = this;
    $.post("reply.php", {
        commentid: id,
        reply: replytext
      },
      function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
        $("textarea").val("");
        // load page then open this box 
        $("#CommentPage").load("comments.php", function() {
          $(foo).parents(".replymsg").prev(".feedback").show();
        });
      });
  });
});
//Hides reply divs,opens form when comment box is clicked 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".feedback").hide();
  $(".replymsg").hide();
  $(".box").on("click", function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".s").toggle();
    $(".box").disableselection();
  });
});
```

#CommentPage is a div created on another script page.

Comment: Are you missing the closing tag from div class='feedback' or is it actually nesting the replymsg ?

Comment: Appologies,I just forgot to put it in for the question but it's in my origional code,it goes just before the div class='replymsg'

Comment: $(foo).parents(".replymsg").prev(".feedback").show();  This line of code is not working

Comment: @ticktock isn't the .feedback div you are trying to show already visible?

Comment: The div opens when the user is sending a reply message( User clicks on the comment they are replying to and reply messages and a form drops down),the reply message is sent to database,page is reloaded and the divs close. Where the user is replying to a comment I want those divs to open. I have found a solution around the problem but it would be nice to know why I can't select the div and show it using Jquery after I have used .load() function.

Comment: @ticktock that block of code is executed on the success of the ajax call if you stay in the same page. If you reload the page, there's no reason for it to be executed

Comment: @Mazz ,it just looks better, if there are 50 comments and everything closes the user has to search for the comment he/she has replied to.

Comment: @ticktock with "there's no reason for it to be executed" I just wanted to say "it will not be executed"

Comment: @ Mazz Ok,Thanks for trying to help!